# Can asynchronous calls to WriteFile result in torn writes?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, asynchronous

I have hypothetical scenario where a file handle opened in asynchronous mode, and some threads which are appending to that file handle. They append by setting the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` parts of the `OVERLAPPED` structure to `0xFFFFFFFF`, as documented in the [MSDN article for `WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Can I issue a second write in append mode like this before the first append completes, and expect the file to contain the entire contents of the first append followed by the entire contents of the second append? Or must I wait to issue the following asynchronous write until the previous write completes?

Comment: It is a file system driver implementation detail.  I don't see any iron-clad guarantees that IRPs are strictly completed in order.  Ought to work okay but I doubt you'll get a warranty.

Comment: What I usually say about hypothetical scenarios is wing it, then tell us the results :P. If the second write call does not have as much to write as the first call, then I believe that the file will receive the second append before the first, otherwise the file should contain the first append follow by the second.

Comment: @John: The reason I ask this is to influence a more high level design decision -- if I have to create a queue of things then copying around a file reference is no longer `sizeof(HANDLE)` -- it becomes very expensive. Actually setting the scenario up seems like a lot of work. Moreover, just because it works on one machine in one instance does *not* mean that it is okay to rely on that behavior. The contract between you and the OS is the documentation, not one particular OS's implementation.

Comment: @Hans: It doesn't matter in what order the IRPs get completed; so long as the written slices are positioned correctly once all IRPs are completed and the file is closed. Though given that nobody has come up with a docs reference yet, I think you're right overall -- I can't assume this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It works. I worked at a company that used a similar scheme, although to get their seek calls to work each time, the predefined the file at a known size (about 2Gb...) then truncated the file at the end.

However, you can just "append" by going to the right location before each write. You'll have to handle the position yourself though.

And also each thread must access the file atomically, "of course."

A simple example:

```
lock mutex
seek to position
write data
position += data size
unlock mutex
```

Of course here I assume that the file is properly opened before you call this function from any thread.

The one thing that you cannot do, unless you create a large file first (which is very fast since files with all zeroes are created virtually), is seek at a position depending on something such as a frame number. So if thread 3 wants to write at "size * 3" and that happens before thread 2 writes at "size * 2" then the seek() will fail...

Comment: Seeking to a position doesn't do anything with asynchronous IO -- in asynchronous mode, `WriteFile` only cares about the position declared in the `OVERLAPPED` structure. So I may only have to synchronize the position integer. Hmmmm...

Comment: Ah! That's right, it has been a while... If you have a mutex (and you'll need it) then it will work just fine. The position is changed when the mutex is locked and thus you have the correct position each time. As I mentioned, the only problem you'd run into is if your threads need to write is a specific order. If so, you'd need to preallocate the file to be able to seek ahead.

Comment: Mutex or InterlockedAdd.

Answer (score 0):

You should never issue multiple outstanding **WriteFile** operations with offset set to **0xFFFFFFFF** even from a single thread. This will cause issue where multiple calls try to access the end of data at the same time and will lead to data corruption. This is due to the fact that if **WriteFile** operates in asynch mode and there are other outstanding **WriteFile** in process using the end of file, some operations might write data to the end of file and other outstanding operations will get wrong end of file pointer. In short you should use **0xFFFFFFFF** only 1 time and wait for the operation to finish to issue another one using that offset. Otherwise you need to calculate the offsets yourself so that each outstanding write operation uses a unique offset. This bug took me 3 days to find about due to poor MSDN documentation about that offset.